# angularjs access denied when performing cross domain requests only in IE11 specific build

Tags: angularjs, cors, internet-explorer-11

I have an AngularJS app using routes and making a lot of cross domain calls. I am using AngularJS and angular-route both v1.5.7 are loaded in the head. Upon a button a click, during login, a GET cross domain call is performed.

This works in all  the browsers and in IE11 but not in this specific version of IE11 v11.0.9600.16476

The error I get is [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W8s0.png)

Does AngularJS v1.5.7 work with IE11 without the use of XDomainRequest?

Using XDomain is not really an option for me because the web service may connecting to users own local copy of the web service which is part of their custom installation of our software and it may be behind their firewall. How do I know the URL of the web service? I ask for it when they are logging in.

So I cannot set up XDomain libraries because I do not know the Slave attribute until the users enters the URL and clicks on submit during login.

Comment: we have decided to not do anything and release the Microsoft office 365 app anyways